# Execute a series of commands in PSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, psql

I am looking for a solution to execute multiple commands in PSQL.

Lets say I have a file with 2 **name** for *database*.

```
1. slave1
2. slave2
```

I already have a master template named "`master_db`".

If I would do it manually, I will do the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE slave1 TEMPLATE master_db;
CREATE DATABASE slave2 TEMPLATE master_db;
```

If there were only 2, it would be very easy but in my case there are more than 30, hence I would like to know if we can create a script. I did try to search but couldn't find a solution.

The databases are in the same cluster, if that matters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using `psql` 9.6+, there is a very convenient command called `\gexec`:

> Sends the current query input buffer to the server, then treats each
>   column of each row of the query's output (if any) as a SQL statement
>   to be executed. [...] The generated queries are executed in the order
>   in which the rows are returned, and left-to-right within each row if
>   there is more than one column. NULL fields are ignored. The generated
>   queries are sent literally to the server for processing, so they
>   cannot be psql meta-commands nor contain psql variable references.

So, your script could look like:

```
SELECT format('create database slave%s template master_db', l_num) 
  FROM generate_series(1, 30) t(l_num);

\gexec
```

Note that you can use the newer `psql` version, even if the server version is lower.  There might be some rare cases of incompatibility (when using `\d*` commands, because some system views may change between server versions), but I haven't yet seen such a case.

If you are still stuck on an earlier client version, you can just use the `SELECT` and copy the output manually to a script file.

If your database names are in a file, you have multiple options.  Either treat that file with an editor (something like `sed -i -e 's/^/CREATE\ DATABASE\ /' -e 's/$/\ TEMPLATE\ master_db'` in any OS where `sed` exists), and then run the resulting script.

Alternatively, you can also do something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE db_names (db text);

\copy db_names FROM 'path/to/your/file'

SELECT format('create database slave%s template master_db', db) 
  FROM db_names;

\gexec
```

**Important note:** only use \gexec when you absolutely trust the source you are working with.  The above approach is prone to [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) (which, interestingly, not so easy when one of the commands on the same line is `CREATE DATABASE`, but it's always better to be careful than sorry later).

Comment: Is there a possibility of having all the database names in a file and running a procedure around that file? OP might have a file containing 30 different database names.